# how to turn Csv data to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I used pandas to read the csv file and was able to create a dictionary from it but need to create the dictionary as a specific format.

```
flightinfo = pd.read_csv('flightdata.csv',quotechar='"',names=['starting_airport', 'destination_airport', 'airline', 'time', 'start_state','end_state'], header=None)

flightinfodict = flightinfo.to_dict(orient='records')
```

this gives the output

```
[{'starting_airport': 'Hilo International Airport', 'destination_airport': 'Boise Airport ', 'airline': 'delta', 'average_time_taken': 300, 'start_state': 'HAWAII', 'end_state': 'IDAHO'}
```

but the output i need is

```
{'Hilo International Airport' : {'destination_airport': 'Boise Airport ', 'airline': 'delta', 'average_time_taken': 300}
```

how can i modify the code to produce this output

thanks

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-values-a-csv-to-a-dictionary-in-python This could be a good solution to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `starting_airport` as index and use `to_dict(orient='index')`:

```
flightinfodict.set_index('starting_airport').to_dict(orient='index')
```

Output:

```
{'Hilo International Airport': {'destination_airport': 'Boise Airport ',
  'airline': 'delta',
  'average_time_taken': 300,
  'start_state': 'HAWAII',
  'end_state': 'IDAHO'}}
```

Or:

```
df.set_index('starting_airport')[['destination_airport','airline','average_time_taken']].to_dict(orient='index')
```

since you indicate you need only these three columns in the dict.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i have 100 rows of data and the orient = 'index' doesnt work with this method it returns,  raise ValueError("DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.")
ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.

Comment: This means that you have multiple similar values in the `starting_airport` column. The output you desired is thereby not possible (you can't have a dict with similar keys). I'm not sure what output you want then, but you could try this: `df.groupby('starting_airport')[['destination_airport','airline','average_time_taken']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more sophisticated way of doing it, but this processing of the record-oriented dict should do the job:

```
def get_dict_without(d, key_to_remove):
  d.pop(key_to_remove)
  return d


new_flightinfodict = [{rec["starting_airport"]: get_dict_without(rec, "starting_airport")} for rec in flightinfodict]
```